# CPPREST redirect location for response code 302

Tags: c++, casablanca

I am using CPPREST http_client to get a RSS feed from :

http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68

but I am receiving redirect response code : 302

When i check the body of the response it is :

> Received response status code:302
>
> response is [HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>
> Age: 0
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2016 06:30:48 GMT
>
> Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=100
>
> Location: http://www.20min.ch/redirect?url=www.20min.ch:80
>
> Server: Kaesebrot 1.23-rc1
>
> ....
>
> Redirecting to http://www.20min.ch/redirect?url=www.20min.ch:80">http://www.20min.ch/redirect?url=

Now when I retry with URL received in location field of response i.e. http://www.20min.ch/redirect?url=www.20min.ch:80

I still get the same response of 302.

M I using the wrong redirect URL?

Also for finding the redirect url in CPPREST I could not find any direct method , I had to find the search the response body and find the substr.

I have also retried with :
 http://www.20min.ch:80/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68
but same 302 respone.
Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

> Location: http://www.20min.ch/redirect?url=www.20min.ch:80

looks like a cyclic redirect to me.